# Nested JSONArray

Tags: java, arrays, json

I need to read a JSON file with following form:

```
{
"Data":[{
"foo":"22",
"bar":"33",
"array":[
{
"1foo":"22",
"1bar":"33"
},
{
"2foo":"22",
"2bar":"33",
}
],
"anotherData":{
"foofoo":"22",
"barbar":"33"
},
"some more data":"11",
"some more data":"11"
},
{and the cycle here starts again from -->
"foo":"22",
"bar":"33",
"array":[
```

My question stands : How do I access individual elements given it's sometimes JSONObject and sometimes JSONArray. I tried using org.json library but I'm failing to access anything after this line -> "array":[. I tried various combinations of JSONObject and JSONArray up to no avail.

My latest code looked something like this:

```
List<Data> data= new ArrayList<>();
        String rawJson = getJsonAsString();
        JSONObject outer = new JSONObject(rawJson);
        JSONArray jArr= outer.getJSONArray("Data");
        JSONObject inner= outer.getJSONObject("array");
for(int i =0; i<jArr.length(); i++){
JSONObject jsonEvent = jArr.getJSONObject(i);

String foo = jsonEvent.getString("foo"); <-- this works,
String 1foo = jsonEvent.getString("1foo"); <-- but this doesn't and i cant access it
```

I tried dozens of different solutions(tried myself and tried to find something here as well, but every case with those nested arrays is different and I can't add those solutions together to get answer for my case)

Answer (score 0):

You can increase your readability if you beautify your raw JSON string:

```json
{
   "Data":[
      {
         "foo":"22",
         "bar":"33",
         "array":[
            {
               "1foo":"22",
               "1bar":"33"
            },
            {
               "2foo":"22",
               "2bar":"33"
            }
         ],
         "anotherData":{
            "foofoo":"22",
            "barbar":"33"
         },
         "some more data":"11",
         "some more data":"11"
      },
      { and the cycle here starts again from -->
         "foo":"22",
         "bar":"33",
         "array":[
            ...
         ],
         ...
      }
   ]
}
```

So, stick to the following code:

```java
JSONArray jArr = outer.getJSONArray("Data");
```

`jArr` is now filled with array of your Object.

And to loop through your Object array, you can use a **for-loop** which you have done it correctly.

```java
for (int i = 0; i < jArr.length(); i++) {
    // The below gets your Object
    JSONObject jsonEvent = jArr.getJSONObject(i);
}
```

And now each `jsonEvent` contains your Object, which you can access the Object by their type.

For example, if you would like to access `foo`, you can use:

```java
String foo = jsonEvent.getString("foo"); // foo = "22"
String bar = jsonEvent.getString("bar"); // bar = "33"
// Note that your array is another Array, you need to get it as JSONArray first
JSONArray arrayJson = jsonEvent.getJSONArray("array");
```

And as `1foo` is in the first Object for your `array`, you need to access it like this:

```java
JSONObject firstObjectInArray = arrayJson.getJSONObject(0);
String target = firstObjectInArray.getString("1foo"); // target = "22"
```

And to access `foofoo`, as it is an attribute of the **JSON Object** `anotherData`, so you should obtain `anotherData` as `JSONObject` first, and then you can access `foofoo`:

```java
JSONObject anotherDataObject = jsonEvent.getJSONObject("anotherData");
String foofoo = anotherDataObject.getString("foofoo"); // foofoo = "22"
```

So the full code within your **for-loop** should look like this:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < jArr.length(); i++) {
    // The below gets your Object
    JSONObject jsonEvent = jArr.getJSONObject(i);

    String foo = jsonEvent.getString("foo");
    JSONArray arrayJson = jsonEvent.getJSONArray("array");
    String target = arrayJson.getJSONObject(0).getString("1foo");

    // Add to get foofoo
    JSONObject anotherDataObject = jsonEvent.getJSONObject("anotherData");
    String foofoo = anotherDataObject.getString("foofoo");
}
```

Comment: yes, this worked, thanks!! But i also seem to have another problem, i'm also trying to access 
```
"anotherData":{
            "foofoo":"22",
```
and i tried something like this-  
```
JSONObject anotherData= (JSONObject) jsonEvent.get("venue");
...
String anotherDataExample = anotherData.get("foofoo").toString();
```
since it's the same "column" of data, but i can't seem to be able to hack it, because i get 
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.json.JSONObject$Null cannot be cast to class org.json.JSONObject,
when i know it's not null...

Comment: I have made an edit accordingly. Please check if it matches with your case.

Comment: i tried this already, it's telling me that anotherData is not a JSONObject

Comment: Can you help to check the following? 1. Does my beautified JSON String, especially those near```anotherData```, match with your one? 2. Are you passing the correct key name for ```anotherData```? 3. Does every **cycle** contain ```anotherData```? If any **cycle** does not possess ```anotherData```, it may also throw exception.

Comment: one of the anotherData entries was a null... Thank You very much for Your patience and insight, You made a noob dev learn a new trick or two:)